# InverseFunction fails to invert $e^{-x/2}-e^{x/2}$

Tags: equation-solving, functions, inverse

I need to invert a function. I want to isolate the `x` basically. By the looks of the graphic I plotted, the function seems to be invertible, however when I call `InverseFunction` it doesn't return an output.

Here is my code:

```
g[x_] := E^(-x/2) - E^(x/2)
Plot[g[x], {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
InverseFunction[g[x]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InverseFunction` operates on an abstract function, yielding an abstract, anonymous function. `g[x]` is not a function, but a formula. Just leave out `[x]`.

On 11.3, MacOS:

```
InverseFunction[g]
(* 2 Log[1/2 (-#1 - Sqrt[4 + #1^2])] & *)
```

Unfortunately, although it's an inverse, this doesn't appear to be the branch you want.

More:

You can get @Henrik Schumacher's answer mindlessly by manipulating the defining expression for `g` (using `=` to evaluate before defining):

```
g[x_] = E^(-x/2) - E^(x/2) // ExpToTrig
(* -2 Sinh[x/2] *)
```

This coaxes `InverseFunction` onto the branch you probably want:

```
InverseFunction[g]
(* -2 ArcSinh[#1/2] & *)
```

Comment: Hello John, using this code the return I obtain is just g^(-1).

Comment: Hello John, can you send me your full code? For the first branch you calculated.

Comment: In a fresh kernel, `g[x_] := E^(-x/2) - E^(x/2); ginv=InverseFunction[g]`. `g[ginv[y]] // FullSimplify` yields `y`, but `ginv[g[y]]` winds up on the wrong branch.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it manually and then it became clearer in the code. Now it works!

Answer (score 6):

Your function `g` is equal to `-2 Sinh[x/2]`:

```
g[x_] := E^(-x/2) - E^(x/2);
FullSimplify[-2 Sinh[x/2] == g[x]]
```

> True

So you are looking for

```
ginv[y_] := -2 ArcSinh[y/2]
```

Comment: Hello Henrik! That is a life saver, how did you figure that out? Is there any principle or rule? If possible do you have time to explain how -2 Sinh[x/2] == g[x]?

Comment: No principle behind that. Basically, `Sinh[x] == (E^x - E^-x)/2` is the _definition_ of the sinus hyperbolicus.

Comment: `g[x] // ExpToTrig`

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to get the correct inverse function using `Solve`, which allows me to specify that the function is defined on the real axis:

```
Clear[x, y];
g[x_] := E^(-x/2) - E^(x/2)

gInverse[y_] = ExpToTrig[x /. First@Solve[g[x] == y, x, Reals]]

(* ==> -2 ArcSinh[y/2] *)
```